# Look up SDO_GEOMETRY validation error code using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, error-code, oracle18c, oracle-spatial

I have a query that validates an SDO_GEOMETRY in Oracle 18c:

```
select
    sdo_geom.validate_geometry_with_context(   
        sdo_geometry ('polygon ((676832.320 4857578.086, 665287.423 4857578.086, 665277.423 4878109.585, 
                                 676832.320 4878119.585, 676842.320 4857588.086))', 26917)
                                     , 0.005) as validation
from
    dual


VALIDATION                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
-----------------------------
13348 [Element <1>] [Ring <1>]

(1 row selected.)
```

[image]

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d6e032ebc71db9f2eba947772dea2c6a)

The query produces an error code **in a text column**, but it doesn't describe what the code means.

I *am* able look up the error manually in the docs: [82 ORA-12700 to ORA-19400](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/errmg/ORA-12700.html#GUID-E6873876-0D0A-456E-B89B-F5A2E41F0638:%7E:text=polygon%20boundary%20is%20not%20closed)

> ORA-13348: polygon boundary is not closed
>
> Cause: The boundary of a
> polygon does not close.
>
> Action: Alter the coordinate values or the
> definition of the SDO_GTYPE or SDO_ETYPE attribute of the geometry.

But manually looking up those error codes is inconvenient.

Is there a way to enhance the query so  that it returns the full error description? (get the description from the database)

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow.  If your query throws an error, you'd get the error message along with the error number in the error stack.  Are you wrapping this query in a block that is catching the exception and reporting only the `SQLCODE` rather than the `SQLCODE` and the `SQLERRM` and/or the `dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can parse the string to pull out the error message, you can pass it to `sqlerrm` to get the text of the error (note that you're apparently getting a positive value, you'd need to negate that value to pass it to `sqlerrm`).  I would assume that you could just look for everything before the first space to get the error number but I don't have a huge sample set to work with.

```
declare
  l_message varchar2(1000);
begin
  l_message := sqlerrm( -13348 );
  dbms_output.put_line( l_message );
end;
/
```

will print

```
ORA-13348: polygon boundary is not closed
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @JustinCave's answer, here's a custom function that gets the error description from the validation text:

```
with function error_description(validation in varchar2) return varchar2 is
begin
    return sqlerrm(substr(validation, 1, instr(validation,' ') - 1) * -1);  --Multiply by -1. Oracle error codes seem to be "negative".
end;
    
select
    error_description(validation) as error_description
from
    (select
        sdo_geom.validate_geometry_with_context(   
            sdo_geometry ('polygon ((676832.320 4857578.086, 665287.423 4857578.086, 665277.423 4878109.585, 676832.320 4878119.585, 676842.320 4857588.086))', 26917), 0.005) as validation
    from dual)

ERROR_DESCRIPTION
-------------------
ORA-13348: polygon boundary is not closed
```

---

**Edit:**

As pointed out by @SolomonYakobson in a related post, the SQLERRM() function can also be used in a SELECT query (without the need for a custom function).

> [Are certain kinds of Oracle functions only available in PL/SQL, not
> SQL?](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/16838144)
>
> Many of the functions are defined in Oracle supplied package
> SYS.STANDARD.
>
> Example: `SELECT SYS.STANDARD.SQLERRM(-1422) FROM DUAL;`

So we just need to fully qualify the function: `SYS.STANDARD.SQLERRM()`

```
select
    sys.standard.sqlerrm(substr(validation, 1, instr(validation,' ') - 1) * -1) error_description
from
    (select
        sdo_geom.validate_geometry_with_context(   
            sdo_geometry ('polygon ((676832.320 4857578.086, 665287.423 4857578.086, 665277.423 4878109.585, 676832.320 4878119.585, 676842.320 4857588.086))', 26917), 0.005) as validation
    from dual)


ERROR_DESCRIPTION
---------------------
ORA-13348: polygon boundary is not closed
```